# building OR expression from List of strings

Tags: c#, linq

In the code below :

```
Expression<Func<WorkflowTask, bool>> filterBefore = wt => true;

filterBefore = filterBefore.And(wt => wt.code == "XK");

List<string> sourceLanguages = new List<string>() { "FR", "DE", "NL" };

//HOW TO BUILD OR CONDITIONS DYNAMICALLY BASED ON SOURCE LANGUAGES LIST  ? 
filterBefore = filterBefore.And(wt => wt.SourceLanguages.Contains("FR") || wt.WorkflowTaskContextualInfo.SourceLanguages.Contains("DE"));
```

I don't know how to build dynamically the OR condition on the `SourceLanguages` List. That list could contain any number of values (I've hardcoded it here for the sake of example).

`wt.WorkflowTaskContextualInfo.SourceLanguages` is a string with comma-separated values `("FR, EN" for instance)`

The `And` expression is defined as below :

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
```

Comment: I assume `filterBefore` is being passed to a LINQ method? Are you trying to dynamically do `filterBefore.Or(x).Or(y).Or(z)` for each string in `sourceLanguages`?

Comment: `filterBefore` is passed to the Where clause of  a LINQ query indeed. Yes, that's pretty much what I'm trying to do, except I have to ANDed this ORs with the previous filterBefore (2nd line of code)

Comment: Where does your `And` method come from? That isn't part of `System.Linq.Expressions`

Comment: hum indeed, I had not realized that (I didn't write that code, I'm just trying to add new features). I've updated my post with the definition of the `And` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQKit's [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) is designed specifically to address this kind of need. But if you feel that's too much overhead, you can craft your own Expression tree with a few simple utilities, as I've described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414456/120955)

First, a general-purpose Expression Replacer:

```
public class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Func<Expression, Expression> replacer;

    public ExpressionReplacer(Func<Expression, Expression> replacer)
    {
        this.replacer = replacer;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return base.Visit(replacer(node));
    }
}
```

Next, a simple utility method to replace one parameter's usage with another parameter in a given expression:

```
public static T ReplaceParameter<T>(T expr, ParameterExpression toReplace, ParameterExpression replacement)
    where T : Expression
{
    var replacer = new ExpressionReplacer(e => e == toReplace ? replacement : e);
    return (T)replacer.Visit(expr);
}
```

This is necessary because the lambda parameters in two different expressions are actually different parameters, even when they have the same name. For example, if you want to end up with `q => q.first.Contains(first) || q.last.Contains(last)`, then the `q` in `q.last.Contains(last)` must be the *exact same* `q` that's provided at the beginning of the lambda expression.

Next we need a general-purpose `Join` method that's capable of joining `Func<T, TReturn>`-style Lambda Expressions together with a given Binary Expression generator.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> Join<T, TReturn>(Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression> joiner, IReadOnlyCollection<Expression<Func<T, TReturn>>> expressions)
{
    if (!expressions.Any())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("No expressions were provided");
    }
    var firstExpression = expressions.First();
    var otherExpressions = expressions.Skip(1);
    var firstParameter = firstExpression.Parameters.Single();
    var otherExpressionsWithParameterReplaced = otherExpressions.Select(e => ReplaceParameter(e.Body, e.Parameters.Single(), firstParameter));
    var bodies = new[] { firstExpression.Body }.Concat(otherExpressionsWithParameterReplaced);
    var joinedBodies = bodies.Aggregate(joiner);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TReturn>>(joinedBodies, firstParameter);
}
```

Now, applying that to your example:

```
    Expression<Func<WorkflowTask, bool>> codeCriteria = wt => wt.code == "XK";
    var langCriteria = new List<string>() { "FR", "DE", "NL" }
    .Select(lang => (Expression<Func<WorkflowTask, bool>>)(wt => wt.SourceLanguages.Contains(lang)))
    .ToList();

    var filter = Join(Expression.And, new[] { codeCriteria, Join(Expression.Or, langCriteria)});
```

`filter` will now have the equivalent of `wt => wt.code == "XK" && (wt.SourceLanguages.Contains("FR") || wt.SourceLanguages.Contains("DE") || wt.SourceLanguages.Contains("NL"))`

Comment: Thanks for the effort ! Quick question... would that work with NHibernate ? I'm not sure I understand all of it so there's no point in coding it if my ORM doesn't support this.

Comment: @Sam: I have no way to test it, but the Expression tree you produce this way will be identical to what you'd produce by manually constructing the expression in code (e.g. `wt => wt.SourceLanguages.Contains(lang1) || w.SourceLanguages.Contains(lang2)...`). So I have every reason to believe it'll work.

Comment: BTW, remember to include special logic for when there are no languages. The Join method will throw an exception if it's passed an empty collection, whereas I'm guessing having no languages selected in your case means you'll want to avoid adding that criteria to the query at all.

Comment: yes indeed, I already have some logic to prevent adding the filter if there are no languages selected. If it translates to a regular OR filter, then it should work because when I hardcode the filter this way it works. I'll give it a try tomorrow. thanks !

Comment: in the end I have used PredicateBuilder as per your recommendation. It's working like a charm :)  Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

I would put the required languages in an array or list.

```
var required = new string[]{ "FR", "DE" };
```

Then you can query with

```
wt => required.Any(r => wt.SourceLanguages.Contains(r))
```

or, the other way round

```
wt => wt.SourceLanguages.Any(sl => required.Contains(sl))
```

Comment: This would work indeed and it answers the question. But I'm out of luck because I use NHibernate and it crashes at runtime with the the "Not supported method" error. I guess it has to be written in another way for NH to handle it and convert it to SQL correctly.

Comment: Yeah, this would totally make sense with LINQ to Objects, but I think most ORMs aren't smart enough to translate that expression correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I did not feel like importing a whole library, and the sample given seemed a bit of a stretch so I think i found an easier solution using `BinaryExpression Update(Expression left, LambdaExpression? conversion, Expression right)`.

The samples below accepts a list of `string`, and constructs a chain of `OR` expressions. Each `OR` expressions calls a entity framework's `LIKE` method. In the end the whole ordeal gets translated nicely to SQL - so if you're on the job of making dynamic filters like i did - this should help you out.

```cs
private static Expression<Func<TMeta, bool>> GetMetaKeyFilterPredicateExpression<TMeta>(List<string> metaKeyNames)
    where TMeta : IMetaKeyValuePair
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TMeta));
    var property = Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(parameter, typeof(IMetaKeyValuePair)),
        propertyName: nameof(IMetaKeyValuePair.MetaKey));
    Expression body = null!;

    BinaryExpression? predicateExpression = null;

    foreach (var metaKeyName in metaKeyNames)
    {
        var likeExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions),
            nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like),
            null,
            Expression.Constant(EF.Functions),
            property,
            Expression.Constant(metaKeyName)
        );

        predicateExpression =
            predicateExpression == null
                ? Expression.Or(likeExpression, Expression.Constant(false))
                : predicateExpression.Update(predicateExpression, null, likeExpression);
    }

    body = (Expression?)predicateExpression ?? Expression.Constant(true);

    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TMeta, bool>>(body: body, parameter);
    return expr;
}
```

```cs
var expr = GetMetaKeyFilterPredicateExpression<TMeta>(metaKeyNames);
qMetaKeyValuePairs = qMetaKeyValuePairs.Where(expr);
```